# MQTT on Ubuntu VM can’t connect to Node-Red

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I’m attempting to create Mosquitto MQTT Broker on Ubuntu VM. When i use sever localhost or ip 127.0.0.1, i can connect, but with ip 192.168.1.100 is not. This is my first time i create broker and i dont know how to fix it!
[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO5kl.png)

Comment: please take the [tour] read [ask] then [edit] accordingly

Comment: Is the VM's IP address really 192.168.1.100. Are you sure? Maybe it changed.

Comment: i use "ifconfig" in terminal, it has 2 ip "192.168.1.100" and "127.0.0.1". I try using putty with ip "192.168.1.100" and it works. But when i test mqtt it cant. I checked ip VM again

Answer (score 0):

For an example of installing an Mosquitto MQTT, where server and client on the same node, can be seen on this article.

https://bckinfo.com/applications/how-to-install-mosquitto-mqtt-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I hope it can help. Thank you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1182531)